# Unicode names of tables/columns in mssql db and sqlalchemy

Tags: unicode, sqlalchemy, pymssql

I'm using latest sqlalchemy and latest pymssql from pip to connect mssql server 8.00.2039 (2005?) The difficulty is table and column names are in russian. Is it possible to handle this database with sqlalchemy? At least i have to make 'select ... where' queries.

```py
engine = create_engine("mssql+pymssql://%s:%s@RTBD/rt?charset=utf8" % (settings.RT_USER, settings.RT_PWD), echo = True, encoding = 'utf8')
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only = [u"Заказы",])
orders = metadata.tables[u'Заказы']
res = engine.execute(orders.select(orders.c[u'Номер заказа'] == u'14-01-0001'))
```

Exception is

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-50ce93243d1c> in <module>()
----> 1 engine.execute(orders.select(orders.c[orders.columns.keys()[0]] == u'14-01-0001'))

python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.pyc in execute(self, statement, *multiparams, **params)
   1680 
   1681         connection = self.contextual_connect(close_with_result=True)
-> 1682         return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
   1683 
   1684     def scalar(self, statement, *multiparams, **params):

python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.pyc in execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params)
    718                                 type(object))
    719         else:
--> 720             return meth(self, multiparams, params)
    721 
    722     def _execute_function(self, func, multiparams, params):

python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.pyc in _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params)
    315 
    316     def _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params):
--> 317         return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
    318 
    319     def unique_params(self, *optionaldict, **kwargs):

python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.pyc in _execute_clauseelement(self, elem, multiparams, params)
    815             compiled_sql,
    816             distilled_params,
--> 817             compiled_sql, distilled_params
    818         )
    819         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.pyc in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
    945                                 parameters,
    946                                 cursor,
--> 947                                 context)
    948 
    949         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.pyc in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1109                                 )
   1110 
-> 1111             util.reraise(*exc_info)
   1112 
   1113         finally:

python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.pyc in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
    938                                      statement,
    939                                      parameters,
--> 940                                      context)
    941         except Exception as e:
    942             self._handle_dbapi_exception(

python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.pyc in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    433 
    434     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 435         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    436 
    437     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

python2.7/site-packages/pymssql.so in pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:6057)()

python2.7/site-packages/_mssql.so in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query (_mssql.c:9858)()

python2.7/site-packages/_mssql.so in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query (_mssql.c:9734)()

python2.7/site-packages/_mssql.so in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query (_mssql.c:10814)()

python2.7/site-packages/_mssql.so in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_sql_command (_mssql.c:11042)()

python2.7/site-packages/_mssql.so in _mssql._substitute_params (_mssql.c:18359)()

<type 'str'>: (<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>, UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'params dictionary did not contain value for placeholder: \u041d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440 \u0437\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430_1', 57, 62, 'ordinal not in range(128)'))
```

The query is right and ends with `WHERE [Заказы].[Номер заказа] = %(Номер заказа_1)s`

But info message from sqla is `INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'\xd0\x9d\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80 \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0_1': '14-01-0001'}`

The strings `\xd0\x9d\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80 \xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0_1` and `\u041d\u043e\u043c\u0435\u0440 \u0437\u0430\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430_1` are equal to `Номер заказа_1`

Answer (score 2):

as stated on the mailing list, FreeTDS and such are very picky about this.   The following test works for me but for the poster above it did not work:

1. UnixODBC 2.3.0
2. FreeTDS 0.91
3. Pyodbc 3.0.7
4. Linux, not OSX, OSX has tons of problems with tds / pyodbc, I’m running on a Fedora 14 machine here

Freetds setting:

```
[sqlserver_2008_vmware]
        host = 172.16.248.142
        port = 1213
        tds version = 7.2
        client charset = UTF8
        text size = 50000000
```

Test script:

```
# coding: utf-8
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, String

e = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger@ms_2008", echo=True)
#e = create_engine("mssql+pymssql://scott:tiger@172.16.248.142:1213", echo=True)

m = MetaData()

t = Table(u'Заказы', m, Column(u'Номер заказа', String(50)))

m.drop_all(e)
m.create_all(e)

orders = m.tables[u'Заказы']
e.execute(orders.select(orders.c[u'Номер заказа'] == u'14-01-0001'))
```

part of the output:

```
CREATE TABLE [Заказы] (
    [Номер заказа] VARCHAR(50) NULL
)


2014-03-31 20:57:16,266 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ()
2014-03-31 20:57:16,268 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2014-03-31 20:57:16,270 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine SELECT [Заказы].[Номер заказа] 
FROM [Заказы] 
WHERE [Заказы].[Номер заказа] = ?
2014-03-31 20:57:16,270 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine (u'14-01-0001',)
```